# Trying to make div background change color when 2 ids are true

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make each div's  background change color when 2 ids exist. it is not changing the color. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I am brand new to javascript. I have an embedded stylesheet and dont know if the javascript will override the css. 
Also, I know some PHP and want to 'echo' the variables throughout the program so that I can see what the string value is in order to debug my own code. what is the easiest way to do this?

```
function drop(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var image = ev.dataTransfer.getData("content");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(image));
    var mydiv = '';
    for (var i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        if ($('#target'.i).find('#answer'.i).length == 1)
        {
            mydiv = document.getElementById('target'+i);
            mydiv.style.backgroundColor = '#00CC00';
        }
        else
        {
            mydiv = document.getElementById('target'+i);
            mydiv.style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$('#target'.i)` If you're trying to concatenate, you're thinking PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be on this line you have . not + to build the id's correctly.

```
if ($('#target'.i).find('#answer'.i).length == 1)
```

so your code should be:

```
if ($('#target'+i).find('#answer'+i).length == 1)
```

Comment: I tried the + instead of the . but the program still doesn't change the background color.

Comment: Is `#answer` a descendant of `#target`?  Based on your description alone, I was picturing something like `$('#id1, #id2').length > 1`

Comment: I am dropping a div into another div. the answer becomes a child of the target when dropped into it.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind I'm no jQuery wizard, my first notion was something like this:

```
$('div[id^=target]').each(function() {
    var el = $(this).find('div[id^=answer]').addBack();
    el.css('backgroundColor', el.length > 1 ? '#00CC00' : '#FF0000');
});
```

...but then I noticed that unlike your example, I was changing both the parent and child div.  Something like this might be closer to your intent:

```
$('div[id^=target]').css('backgroundColor', function () {
    return $(this).find('div[id^=answer]').length ? '#00CC00' : '#FF0000';
});
```

You also could retain the `for` loop if that's your preference:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    $('div#target' + i).css('backgroundColor', function() {
        return $(this).find('div#answer' + i).length ? '#00CC00' : '#FF0000'; 
    });
}
```

...and, just for fun, something kinda esoteric:

```
$('div[id^=target]:has(div[id^=answer])').css('backgroundColor', '#00CC00');
$('div[id^=target]:not(:has(div[id^=answer]))').css('backgroundColor', '#FF0000');
```

[Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/P3KyT/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RcQBg/)) with the correct operator for concatenation, i.e. with `+` instead of `.`, however here are a few points you should bear in mind :

**Point 1 :**

Among all the `i` variables you're iterating over in your `for` loop, if there is no `div` with `id` equal to `"target" + i` you will end up in the following `else` block :

```
else
{
    mydiv = document.getElementById('target'+i); // null
    mydiv.style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';
}
```

At that place `mydiv` will be `null` and `mydiv.style` will throw an error.

**Point 2 :**

It seems you used jQuery to find the answers elements, while you used `document.getElementById`, which is part of the DOM API, to select then the target element. It would have been more consistent to use jQuery there too.

**Point 3 :**

If you want to simply output the value of some variable you can use `console.log`, which will output in the javascript console of the browser. The `console` object is provided by the browser, therefore you may not have the `console.log` method, but if you are using an up to date browser there is a good chance you will have it.

To summarize, [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RcQBg/1/) for an example that takes these points into account.